# AsyncThrowingStream in CoreBluetooth, how to emulate a finish, error, and cancel

Tags: swift

I have a bluetooth app which connects to a device and sends information to it. The device will process it and send back that it's completed. I wanted to use an AsyncThrowingStream for this, but I am new to it and Swift and all the examples I've found show a request and response in a single block. In my case the message will come back from the peripheral like:

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    print("didUpdateValueFor \(characteristic.uuid)")

    if let error = error {
        print("error:", error)
    }
    
    guard let value = characteristic.value else {
        print("no value received")
        return
    }

    let incomingCommand: UInt8 = value[0]

}
```

The incoming command could give a progress code, error, or finish which could return something like an Int for the id. I saw [this example on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwwKJLrg_0U) which seemed to be the most understandable to me and I adapted it to see if I could emulate what I wanted to do in a simple example. I have the timer updating now (which eventually will be a timeout), but wasn't sure how to call a function to finish, cancel, or error. I created the stubs for them. Can anybody help show with this example how I might alter the send function?

```
import SwiftUI

class TestService {
    
    var handler: ((Int) -> Void)?
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    func startGenerating() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
            
            let number = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
            self?.handler?(number)
        })
    }
    
    func stopGenerating() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    func send() -> AsyncThrowingStream<Int, Error> {
        
        return AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
            
            let testService = TestService()
            
            testService.handler = { number in
                continuation.yield(number)
            }
            
            continuation.onTermination = { @Sendable _ in
                testService.stopGenerating()
            }
            
            testService.startGenerating()
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func updateSend() {
        
    }
    
    func finishSend() {
        
    }
    
    func cancelSend() {
        
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var testService: TestService = TestService()
    @State var currentNumber: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("\(currentNumber)")
            
            
            Button(action: {
                print("start send")
                Task {
                   
                    do {
                        for try await newNumber in testService.send() {
                            currentNumber = newNumber
                        }
                        print("done")
                    } catch {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
 
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Start Send")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
          
            Button(action: {
                print("throw error")
            }, label: {
                Text("Throw Error")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

            Button(action: {
                print("cancelling")
            }, label: {
                Text("Cancel")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("finish send")
                testService.finishSend()
            }, label: {
                Text("Finish Send")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I saw [this post Swift AsyncStream variable, use after finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676044/swift-asyncstream-variable-use-after-finish), but it deals with a button press to start the process, but it would be great to see one for finish as well simulating a finish message from a publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you are trying to do can be done with `.task(id: id)`.

```
.task(id: id, {
    //Only run if the id has a value
    guard id != nil else {return}
    do {
        for try await newNumber in testService.send() {
            currentNumber = newNumber
            //Trigger a stop when something has been met
            if (0...15) ~= currentNumber {
                //Terminate because some condition has been met
                id = nil
            }
        }
        print("done")
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    //reset id
    id = nil
})
```

The rest can be done with a few edits, see comments.

```
import SwiftUI


class TestService {
    
    var handler: ((Int) -> Void)?
    //Handle Error
    var errorHandler: ((Error) -> Void)?
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    func startGenerating() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
            
            let number = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
            self?.handler?(number)
        })
    }
    
    func stopGenerating() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    func send() -> AsyncThrowingStream<Int, Error> {
        
        return AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
                            
            handler = { number in
                continuation.yield(number)
                //Trigger a stop when something has been met
                if (16...30) ~= number {
                    //Terminate because some condition has been met
                    continuation.finish()
                }
            }
            errorHandler = { error in
                continuation.finish(throwing: error)
            }
            
            continuation.onTermination = { @Sendable [weak self] _ in
                guard let self else {return}
                self.stopGenerating()
            }
            
            startGenerating()
            
        }
        
    }
    func updateSend() {
        handler?(Int.random(in: 0..<100))
        
    }
    
    func throwError() {
        errorHandler?(NSError(domain: "sample", code: 99))
    }
}

struct SampleStream: View {
    
    var testService: TestService = TestService()
    @State var currentNumber: Int = 0
    @State private var id: UUID?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(currentNumber) is running = \((id != nil).description)")
            Button(action: {
                print("start send")
                //Start
                id = .init()
            }, label: {
                Text("Start Send")
            })
            //Control Task lifecyle
            .task(id: id, {
                //Only run if the id has a value
                guard id != nil else {return}
                do {
                    for try await newNumber in testService.send() {
                        currentNumber = newNumber
                        //Trigger a stop when something has been met
                        if (0...15) ~= currentNumber {
                            //Terminate because some condition has been met
                            id = nil
                        }
                    }
                    print("done")
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                //reset id
                id = nil
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("throw error")
                testService.throwError()
            }, label: {
                Text("Throw Error")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("cancelling")
                id = nil
            }, label: {
                Text("Cancel")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("finish send")
                id = nil
            }, label: {
                Text("Finish Send")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    SampleStream()
}
```

You can also use `Result` instead of 2 handlers.

```
class TestService {
    
    var handler: ((Result<Int, Error>) -> Void)?
    
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    func startGenerating() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
            
            let number = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
            self?.handler?(.success(number))
        })
    }
    
    func stopGenerating() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    func send() -> AsyncThrowingStream<Int, Error> {
        
        return AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
            
            
            handler = { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let number):
                    continuation.yield(number)
                    //Trigger a stop when something has been met
                    if (16...30) ~= number {
                        //Terminate because some condition has been met
                        continuation.finish()
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.finish(throwing: error)
                }
                
            }
            
            continuation.onTermination = { @Sendable [weak self] _ in
                guard let self else {return}
                self.stopGenerating()
            }
            
            startGenerating()
            
        }
        
    }
    func updateSend() {
        handler?(.success(Int.random(in: 0..<100)))
        
    }
    
    func throwError() {
        handler?(.failure(NSError(domain: "sample", code: 99)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Very comprehensive. Thank you. I'm going through it now and will certainly respond. I see that I can message the process through the handler and the response can be based on the number (or whatever) being passed in the handler. So, I could finish in there as well (demonstrated by the 16...30 in your example). Excellent. So helpful. I'm not sure I got the task id part.

Comment: @lcj the task(Id) can be anything I use an optional UUID for something easy nil == the task stops/isn’t running and not nil == run the task. .task holds on to the asynchronous await portion to give you the ability to cancel it.

Comment: What you have would replace what's in my button action currently?

Comment: @lcj yes, the button action isn’t capable of holding on to the task for stopping/cancelling. That is why action just sets the id, so the task can start.

Comment: Thanks, @lorem ipsum. I think I have it. Now I need to figure out how to loop through a series of the send func so they execute sequentially. That's probably a separate post.

Comment: @lcj this is fully compliant with async/await so anything you put below the “done” print statement will be completed afterwards. It all depends on your triggers though 0…15 would terminate everything but 16….30 would allow the stuff after done.